# Hazelcast: use ConcurrentHashMap or ITopic messaging object to distribute data?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, hazelcast

I have an app distributed in multiple tomcats and using a hazel cast to share data. In the app, I use map that needs to be consistent throughout all the Tomcats. Is there any reason why one should prefer using the message distribution mechanism (ITopic object) to keep consistency when the data in the map changes? Or is the distributed ConcurrentHashMap always the right choice in the described case – when I need the maps in each tomcat to hold the exact same data at all times (operation speed, reliability)?
How does ConcurrentHashMap work under the hood to keep fully consistent in different JVMs? And, on the under hand, how does distribute message work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [IMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html)

[ITopic](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ITopic.html) is asynchronous, so won't achieve your goal of "*the exact same data at all times*".

Comment: Why IMap and not ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: Java's java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap does not span JVMs.If you have multiple Tomcat JVMs you have multiple *independent* instances of ConcurrentHashMap, and then have the worry of ensuring their contents match. Hazelcast's com.hazelcast.core.IMap is essentially like ConcurrentHashMap except that it spans JVMs. If you have multiple Tomcat JVMs they can share access to the one IMap instance, so you don't have to worry about contents deviating (Hazelcast handles this for you).

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it. (1) JVM #1 updates its ConcurrentHashMap (2) JVM #1 uses ITopic to transport this change to JVM #2. (3) JVM #2 updates its ConcurrentHashMap. Each of the ConcurrentHashMap instances may be thread-safe, fast, etc, etc but steps (1) and (3) cannot happen simultaneously. So won't achieve your goal of "the exact same data at all times".

Comment: Ok, that sure is clearer now. If so, why to ever use ITopic? what are its use-cases, as you understand it?

Comment: ITopic is great, but solves a different problem. Imagine an online shop on multiple machines. You might use ITopic to send them tomorrow's promotional rate. It doesn't really matter that they don't all get the message at the exact same time (and it's maybe only microseconds apart) as it's *tomorrow's* code. What you have is a mechanism for one sender to send to some or all of the Tomcat instances, so eventing rather than have them polling, and this may be preferable. Obviously there are other ways to achieve the same, but the more options you have, the better choice you can make.

Answer (score -1):

Use ConcurrentHashMap when you need very high concurrency.

It is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map.

Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.

There is no locking at the object level.

The locking is at a much finer granularity at a hashmap bucket level.

ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.

ConcurrentHashMap uses multitude of locks.

Comment: But what are the advantages of ConcurrentHashMap over ITopic? I believe that ITopic is for the case when the map should not be consistent at all times, but in specific cases, coverred by ITopic.

Comment: That does not answer my questions: which is preferable, why, and how they work?